# dynamic source file paths in excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

Here is an example of my problem :

*here is the worksheet n°1*

[image: Worksheet n°1]

*here is the worksheet n°2*
[image]

I would like to provide the path of a source file and that the informations are deduced from the first worksheet and displayed in the table of the second worksheet.

[EDIT]

Here is the query related to the cell "total of people".
I still don't know how to fetch the information from another file

[image]

Comment: I'm currently following this tutorial :
 https://exceloffthegrid.com/power-query-using-parameters/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial is probably a solution to my issue :
https://exceloffthegrid.com/power-query-source-cell-value/

The exemple file work well but for some reasons I can't use another file with this technique ...

this following line (tblSourceData is the table name of the exemple) :

> Source{[Item="tblSourceData",Kind="Table"]}[Data]

need to be different (Table1 is the table name of my new file) :

> Source{[Item="Table1",Kind="Table"]}[Data]

here is the proof of the table name of my new file :
[image]

But I get this error when I edit the name :
[image]

(I have obviously correctly changed the path to the source file in my cells for this exemple)

[LAST EDIT]

The solution was to don't forget to creat a real Table in the source file with the name "Table1".